# Remote Event Receivers Troubles

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, office-365

So I've been working with the remote event receivers for Sharepoint 2013. I'm working with having them connect to a local IIS server to accept the inbound events as the Visual Studio tools make it easier to to work with the tokens and such. Because of my environment, I'm testing my code on a remote server so I'm publishing it and uploading it to Sharepoint Online Dev Preview and my IIS server (publicly accessible).

I am able to confirm that the AppEventReceivers are in fact working. I've setup an 'Announcement' list in my VS 2012 project, this gets deployed to the AppWeb. I've then setup a RER on this list for when an 'item is added'. However it doesn't fire the Event request to my IIS server.

If I edit the elements and make the URL to my RemoteEventReceiver.svc normal HTTP, it will actually make a request with the following error:

> The requested operation requires an HTTPS (SSL) channel. Ensure that the target endpoint address supports SSL and try again. Target endpoint address:
>
> *`http://-MY ISS SERVER-/SharepointApp3Web/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc`*

This allows me to know that it gets registered and is able to actually communicate with my IIS server. However when I switch it back to HTTPS, nothing appears to happen. No requests are received whatsoever.

I've already posted with no luck on the MSDN forums with little to no response, so figured I would try here.

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. When trying to get it working in HTTPS, did you add the cert and all
   certs in it's path into manage trusts in central admin?
2. You might need to enable oauth over HTTP to get it working in HTTP.  I've seen
   it explained here regarding office web apps: 
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx#scenario1

   New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName RemoteServerName -AllowHTTP

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Steve.  We are currently just working with the Sharepoint Online environment, so as far as I'm aware I don't have access to Central Admin.  I appreciate the help.